# Вычислить сумму членов нескончаемого ряда с точностью до члена ряда, меньшего ε (10-5<=ε<=10-3)

Tags: c++, visual-studio, ряды, численные-методы

[image: Сам ряд]
Это что у меня получилось

```
''' 
    #include <iostream>
#include <cmath>

using namespace std;

 int main()
{
     float a, b, c, n, x=1, a = pow((x-1),2*n-1)/((2*n+1)*pow((x+1),2*n+1));
     cin >> n;
     b = a * 2;
     c = (b - a) * b;
     cout << c;

    return 0;
}
'''
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

А [вот так](https://ideone.com/u1ptKd) не хотите?

```
double series(double x, double eps)
{
    double s = (x-1)/(x+1), t = s;
    x = s*s;
    for(int k = 3; abs(t/k) > eps; k += 2) s += (t *= x)/k;
    return s;
}
```

Кстати, вы даже не пытались решать свою задачу... То, что вы привели в виде кода - в полной мере ни при чем.